# The relation between direct and indirect speech

Tags: syntax, reported-speech, direct-speech

> ‘Mary, I want to take you out to dinner,’ he had lied, to break the
>   frost.

I would like to know what is the syntactic relation between the direct and indirect speech - whether there is any kind of dependency and what we call the reporting clause.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You have given an example of direct speech. Indirect speech is another way of describing the same thing, but there is no *dependency* involved, aside from reporting what was said by paraphrasing it. I also don't know what you mean by *reporting clause*.

Comment: "Mary, I desperately want to take you out to dinner" he had lied only moments before telling her to get lost.  The tense of **he had lied** is independent of the tense in the quoted speech.

Comment: *Only moments before telling Mary to get lost he had lied, saying he desperately wanted to take her out to dinner.*  There, **he ...wanted** is the backshift of direct speech **I ...want**.

Comment: Before asking this question, you have to transform that sentence into indirect speech. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the example, it seems to me that OP wants to know how a direct speech sentence (or one in reported or indirect speech) is related to the main clause that contains the reporting verb.

Let's start with a simpler reporting verb:

> ‘Mary, I want to take you out to dinner,’ he had said.

OR

> He had told Mary he wanted to take her out to dinner.

In both cases, the sentence in direct or reported speech can be considered to be **the direct object of the main verb** "had said" or "had told": *What had he said? -> He had said: Mary, I want to take you out to dinner / What had he told Mary? -> He had told Mary he wanted to take her out to dinner.*

In modern grammar, "that he wanted to take her out to dinner" is called a content clause.

The verb-object relationship is clear with simple reporting verbs like *say, tell, reply, answer, ask.*

With semantically richer verbs  like "lie", the verb-object relationship is not so clear or straightforward because, as Tᴚoɯɐuo suggested, he lied **by saying** that to Mary, or he lied **when he said** that to Mary. In these cases, what was said tends to form part of the concept expressed by the verb. We thus have reporting verbs like *deny, apologize, beg, order, suggest*, etc. which fully or partially include in themselves what the speaker said.